# Open a form from a panel

Tags: c#

I have been working on project for the past one month but I am really stucked. I have a form called MainForm which has 2 panels. One is called MainContainer and other called SubContainer. I have two other forms, one called Login and other SQLSettings. SubContainer is found inside MainContainer. SubContainer is suppose to hold all open forms. When MainForm loads at startup it opens Login form inside SubContainer. Login contains a linklabel which is also suppose to open SQLSettings form in SubContainer but nothing happens when i click on the linklabel in the Login form.

What I have tried:

this is the code for the linklabel which is suppose to open SQLSettings form:
this.Close();

```
MainForm f = new MainForm();
Form cur = new SQLSettings();
f.SubContainer.Dock = DockStyle.None;
f.SubContainer.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
f.SubContainer.Size = cur.Size;
f.SubContainer.Location = new Point(f.MainContainer.Width / 2 - f.SubContainer.Width / 2,
f.MainContainer.Height / 2 - f.SubContainer.Height / 2);
cur.TopLevel = false;
f.SubContainer.Controls.Remove(f.currentForm);
f.SubContainer.Tag = cur;
f.SubContainer.Controls.Add(cur);
f.SubContainer.Tag = cur;
cur.BringToFront();
cur.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Child form can be opened inside the parent form with setting property `MdiParent`.
According to your MainForm as parent and SQLSettings form as child:

```
MainForm f = new MainForm();
Form cur = new SQLSettings();
cur.MdiParent = f;
cur.BringToFront();
cur.Show();
```